# How to add line(strike) through on Text(Discount price cut line ) in react native?

Tags: react-native, text, line

[image][image]

How to add line on above the text as provided in the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

You can use textDecorationLine with 'line-through' property like below

`<Text style={{textDecorationLine: 'line-through', textDecorationStyle: 'solid'}}> Solid line </Text>`